# Designing a circuit to read in pressure sensor values with minimal analog pin availability

Tags: arduino, circuit-design, analog, sensor, kirchhoffs-laws

We are trying to build a project which uses an Arduino Nano to obtain pressure sensor readings from 8-10 sensors. The problem we are running into is that the Nano only has 8 analog pins. Of the 8, 2 will be used for a serial connection to an accelerometer, leaving us with 6 analog pins to use.

We have looked into using a multiplexer, but were wondering if there’s a way to do this purely with voltage ratios. We found this schematic online but can’t make much sense of it.

We want to potentially create some sort of grid with the sensors allowing us to use one analog pin to read in voltage values from more than one sensor.

[image]

TLDR;
Can use maximum 6 analog pins (i.e. can only measure voltage at 6 points.)

Need to read in 10 (8-9 would also be acceptable) separate voltage values.

Is there any way to make a circuit from which we could obtain 9+ voltage readings using only 6 measurements, keeping in mind that the pressure sensor works by giving us variable resistances depending on pressure?

Comment: Multiplex it and be done.  You're going to get yourself a lot of complexity for little gain if you try to mix your signals together.

Comment: You could use an external ADC-Board. There are 16Channel versions (Single-Ended, 12/14/16Bit with Reference) with I2C/SPI interface (Ready-To-Use Librarys) out there for small $.

Comment: 6 equations and 9 unknowns - not gonna have a solution. You would need some kind of state switching to make additional measurements - so just mux it.